# How to fix failed build with no errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm really new to programming. I tried to make some sort of sorting application that sorts an array by swapping the values in the array. But when I try to build it, it just says build failed. Visual Studio doesn't give an error, so I'm kind of stuck. Could you help me out?

I've tried to increase the array size, and made sure there isn't any loop writing more integers to the array than is possible.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int arr[10];
bool sorted = false;
int compare(int x, int y);
int cycle;
int compres;
int slot;

int main()
{
    for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
    {
        cin >> arr[c];
    }
    while (cycle <= 5)
    {
        compres = compare(cycle, cycle + 1);
        if (compres == 1)
        {
            slot = arr[cycle];
            arr[cycle] = arr[cycle + 1];
            arr[cycle + 1] = slot;
            cout << arr[cycle] << " and " << arr[cycle + 1] << "swapped" << endl;
        }
        else if (compres == 0)
        {
            cout << arr[cycle] << " is equal to " << arr[cycle + 1] << endl;
        }
        else if (compres == -1)
        {
            cout << arr[cycle] << " and " << arr[cycle + 1] << "are already sorted" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "(!) Compare issue." << endl;
        }
        cycle++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i];
    }
}

int compare(int x, int y)
{
    if (x > y) { return  1; }
    if (x == y) { return 0; }
    if (x < y) { return -1; }
}
```

Output log: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mw5d.png

Comment: At least no problems with your code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fcacf7d4bf006f07) (besides the warning).

Comment: When I built and started a program in VS (e.g. with Ctrl+F5), then I can compile the sources again but I cannot link. The still running old exe (or involved DLLs) prevent overwriting when VS tries to link. If I remember right VS just states that it cannot link successfully ....dll (or ....exe) in this case.

Comment: Can you show the last few messages from the Output Tab after a build?

Comment: Not sure why you say "Visual Studio doesn't give an error". Your screen shot has two errors (access denied trying to write to log file). Looks like you gave a directory name instead as a file name for your log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something went wrong while creating the project...
I made a new one and copy-pasted the code, it worked.
Thanks for your answers!